# Flatten a list of list in python & also create differenet dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, flatten

I have a data

#create some data with Names column
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Joe', 'John', 'Jasper', 'Jez'] *4, 'Add': ['Lo', 'Po', 'Fa',
    'It']*4,'Ob1' : np.random.rand(16), 'Ob2' : np.random.rand(16)})

[image]

& have created a list with subsets of the data (only with the names I want) using another dataframe as a map

```
import pandas as pd

#Mapping file
data2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Names": ["Joe", "John"],
   "Add": ["Lo", "Po"]})

tuples = [tuple(x) for x in data2.values]
my_dfs = [data[(data['Names'] == mytuple[0]) & (data['Add'] == mytuple[1])] for mytuple in    
tuples]
for my_df in my_dfs:
    print(my_df)
```

& I get the following output:

```
    [ Names Add   Ob1   Ob2
    Joe  Lo 0.999 0.403
    Joe  Lo 0.509 0.570
    Joe  Lo 0.180 0.775
    Joe  Lo 0.010 0.591

    Names Add   Ob1   Ob2
    John  Po 0.040 0.256
    John  Po 0.673 0.869
    John  Po 0.915 0.593
    John  Po 0.865 0.298 ]
```

"my_dfs" is a list of list.Is it possible :

i. To create a dataframe by flattening the list above & how best can it be done. Tried the following but doesn't give me the correct output:

```
flattened_list = []
for x in my_dfs:
    flattened_list.append(x)
```

where the final output will look :

```
   Names Add   Ob1   Ob2
    Joe  Lo 0.999 0.403
    Joe  Lo 0.509 0.570
    Joe  Lo 0.180 0.775
    Joe  Lo 0.010 0.591
    John  Po 0.040 0.256
    John  Po 0.673 0.869
    John  Po 0.915 0.593
    John  Po 0.865 0.298
```

without the headers appearing twice

ii. To create different dataframes (2 dataframes in this case one for Joe & another for John.

```
Joe:

Names Add   Ob1   Ob2
    Joe  Lo 0.999 0.403
    Joe  Lo 0.509 0.570
    Joe  Lo 0.180 0.775
    Joe  Lo 0.010 0.591

John:   

    Names Add   Ob1   Ob2
    John  Po 0.040 0.256
    John  Po 0.673 0.869
    John  Po 0.915 0.593
    John  Po 0.865 0.298
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use [pandas concat function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine your data frames.

If you prefer to use python lists, you want to use lists `extend` function, not `append`:

```
flattened_list = []
for x in my_dfs:
    flattened_list.extend(x)
```

`extend` adds the elements of a list to your list, whereas `append` will just add the list itself to your `flattened_list` list (you can read about it more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/)

Also note that it seems like your lists include the headers, so if you want just the values you can use the python `x[n:]` to get only the elements *after* n:

```
flattened_list = []
for x in my_dfs:
    flattened_list.extend(x[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks , but I get only the headers whereas I want just one header & all the values.      flattened_list = []
for x in my_dfs:
    flattened_list.extend(x[1:])
flattened_list   ['Names', 'Add', 'Ob1', 'Ob2', 'Names', 'Add', 'Ob1', 'Ob2']